# Mongodb: use of $and and $lte condition together

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to fetch the results from mongodb collection using the below query.If I remove the condition of offer_price then all results are returned. But if I add offer_price condition then empty results are fetched even if  such items exists in the collection.

```
db.collection.find( {
$and : [
    {category_name:"Men's Clothing"},
    { $or : [ { description : /.*Kurta.* / }, { description :  /.*Long.* /} ,{ description :  /.*White.* /} ] },
    { offer_price : { $lte : 1000 }  }
   ]
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are missing that the `$and` is not necessary. **ALL** MongoDB query conditions are already "AND" conditions. But most likely your real problem here is that `"offer_price"` actually contains a "string" and not a numeric value. As such there simplt would be no results that actually match the less than or equal to condition. It's a common mistake people make.

Comment: It throws a warning shown below if I don't include the and condition  `PHP Warning:  MongoCollection::find() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given`

Comment: Oh dear!, you need to read more documentation; `{ "category_name":"Men's Clothing", "offer_price": { "$lte": 1000 }, "description": { "$in": [/.*Kurta.* /,/.*Long.* /,/.*White.* /}] } }`. But like I said, as long as the values in `offer_price` are "strings" i.e `"124.25"` as opposed to `124.25` then you are not going to get a match.